# htaccess rewrite virtual folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

im trying to create website, and i need to rewrite php file switch cases to virtual directories.

Im trying to make url of type `http://localhost/en/dashboard/mailbox/send/username`

to work, and its working with the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^([a-z]{2})- [NC]
## Rewrite Rules
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ /index.php?language=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^account/?$ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(account)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$ account.php?language=$1&action=$3 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^dashboard/?$ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(dashboard)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$ /$2.php?language=$1&type=$3&subtype=$4&lasttype=$5 [L,NC,QSA]
```

However, from now i cannot access `http://localhost/en/dashboard/mailbox/` itself

Can someone help me to solve this problem?
Im not into this htaccess thing at all, but i did so far all i could (i think so)

Comment: In `RewriteRule ^dashboard/?$ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]`, where does the `%1` come from?

Comment: Its a language variable acquired by parsing `%{HTTP:Accept-Language}`

Comment: No, it won't. That `RewriteCond` is bound to its following rule. It doesn't apply to __all__ the rules following.

Comment: Problem itself in this part of code `(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))(?:/([^/]+))?)`    If i'll make it `(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?)` i can access mailbox, but not `http://localhost/en/dashboard/mailbox/send/username`  P.S. I can still access `send` procedure

Comment: Try this pattern: `^([a-z]{2})/(dashboard)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$`

Comment: Oh my, that question mark..... Thanks a lot, post it as an answer so i can upvote you)

Comment: @hjpotter92: Terrific troubleshooting mate, post your comments as answer so that OP can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @hjpotter92, this problem was solved.

I missed one question mark, so thats why this code was kind of broken.
Here is correct string:

```
^([a-z]{2})/(dashboard)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$
```

All i missed is
`^([a-z]{2})/(dashboard)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))`**?**`(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$`

And here is fully correct code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^([a-z]{2})- [NC]
## Rewrite Rules
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ /index.php?language=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^account/?$ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(account)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$ account.php?language=$1&action=$3 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^dashboard/?$ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(dashboard)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$ /$2.php?language=$1&type=$3&subtype=$4&lasttype=$5 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: I would think it will be better if @hjpotter92 posts this as answer so that you can give him credit to him by accepting it.

Comment: @anubhava Ah, the issue was just a missing `?` from the OP's part. I'd rather think of it as fixing a typo ;) \@Ivan You can select this post as an answer.